# Why is Google PageRank not showing after redirecting www to non www?

Tags: redirects, pagerank, http, no-www

I have a fashion website. I had redirected my domain `http://` (`non-www`) to `http://www` domain and my preferred domain in Google Webmaster Tools was `http://www`.

Now I have redirected `http://www` to `http://` domain and have changed my prefered domain as well.

Now Google PageRank is not showing for even a single page. Would any body please help me and let me know if I have done something wrong?

Below is my *.htaccess* redirect code:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.deemasfashion\.com$
RewriteRule ^deemasfashion\.com/?(.*)$ http://deemasfashion.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://deemasfashion.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ http://deemasfashion.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: how did you do the redirection?  htaccess?

Comment: @Jon i have edited the question and added the htaccess code.

Comment: how are you measuring page rank?  Also not sure the code works, as when I go to deemasfashion.com I dont get redirected

Comment: i am using chrome extension for pagerank. i have also checked it via http://www.prchecker.info and http://www.prchecker.info/check_page_rank.php

Comment: @Jon currently http://www.deemasfashion.com is redirecting to http://deemasfashion.com

Comment: i mean www domain redirecting to non www domain

Answer (score 2):

Pagerank checkers get their data based on the "toolbar pagerank" that is published by Google.   When changing your URLs, the data won't show up in the Pagerank checkers until Google updates this data.

Google typically updates this data every three or four months.  Unfortunately, the process for updating this data broke at Google and they are not planning to fix it soon.  The [last Pagerank update](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-pagerank-update-2014-17478.html) was in February 2013 and they don't expect another one until at least sometime in 2014.

Internally, Google is still evaluating inbound links to your site.  I have seen no evidence that shows that Google is unable to assign link value to sites internally for ranking purposes.

Having no Pagerank showing is not harming your site in any way.  It is just an unfortunate side effect of Google not refreshing the data that they usually provide about Pagerank.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller. I know all this but 5 to 10 days back main page rank was 3 and few pages were 2 and many pages were 1.

Comment: When you redirect your main URL to a different URL all of that needs to be recomputed.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller , Before redirecting this was the same thing comes in my mind so i experimented it on a different domain. domain is http://saanjhpunjab.org/  http://www.saanjhpunjab.org/ http://saanjhpunjab.org/index.php

Comment: My Pagerank checker is showing PR 3 for all of those.

Comment: i had even removed redirect for all main pages. All pages are accessible non www, www, index.php

Comment: but all showing old page rank 3

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: I stand by my answer that the lack of toolbar pagerank is a display issue from Google that will get fixed when (if) they next update the data.  In the meantime, it won't hurt your site in any way.

Comment: if that was the case then all pages **should have no page rank** or **waiting for pagerank to be calculated / assigned** or **1 PR for each page**

Comment: It is also the case when Google determines that they need to recalculate the PageRank for any reason.